# Pull to refresh library with unscrollable header

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

I have the sequent problem. i need a pull to refresh listview library that can manage a fixed "header" view, and a scrollable list below the header. 
When i scroll down list, header should remain visible (only list elements should scroll), and when i scroll up, when i reach top element list, on pull down to refresh, also header view should move with pull action.
I've try with crhis banes pull to refresh, but without success.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Try this  [link](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh).

Comment: that is the library i already use

Comment: @NehaAgarwal spend some time before providing links.. he already followed your link (mentioned in question)

Comment: Did you try the native SwipeRefreshLayout: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html